# In jenkins which plugin is recommended and secure for connect sql database from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins which plugin is recommended and secure for connect sql database from jenkins

Recommended plugin details

There are mutiple plugins available to connect sql database . Database , Microsoft SQL Server DatabaseVersion ..etc.

Which one is recommended to connect sql database